# How to find which foreign keys are referenced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two classes - `logical_interfaces` and `pop_vlans` with a one-to-one relationship.

In the `logical_interfaces` table the foreign key is `vlan_id` which relates to the `id` column in `pop_vlans`.

In my controller I get a list of `vlan_number`s (stored in `pop_vlans` like so:

```
@vlan_numbers = PopVlan.find_all_by_pop_id(@device.pop.id)
```

(`@device.pop.id` is the `pop` the `pop_vlan` belongs to which is the same as the `device`)

then in my view I generate a select from this collection:

```
<%= collection_select 'logical_interface', "vlan_id", @vlan_numbers, :id, :vlan_number %>
```

This is all fine but I don't want to fetch *all* the `vlan_numbers`, only the ones whose `id` is not referenced in the `logical_interfaces` table. i.e. only those numbers which are not already in use.

I am terribly sorry for the confusion as this is quite a long-winded question to ask something that is hopefully straight-forward.

I think it could be done with a manual SQL query but I have no idea if there are built in methods to allow this to be done 'the Rails way'.

I think the MySQL to achieve the opposite would be `SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans 
LEFT JOIN logical_interfaces ON logical_interfaces.id = pop_vlans.id` but I can't actually think how to adjust that query to find `vlan_numbers` that don't match.

**TLDR**

```
logical_interfaces | pop_vlans
-------------------|-----------
     vlan_id-------|----->id
       ....        |  vlan_number
```

get all from the right table whose foreign key is not referenced in the left table

I am thinking that it might just be a lot easier to add a new column to the table to act as a flag if it's in use and use that as the condition in the query.

Comment: sorry but if you have a `LEFT JOIN` query for your `one-to-one` two tables, it will return the entire rows, so what you call `opposite` is not very clear

Comment: quickly saying, could it be something like `SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE pop_vlans.id, vlan_number NOT IN (SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans INNER JOIN logical_interfaces ON logical_interfaces.id = pop_vlans.id)`

Comment: think you could be right @Newben, will give the above and your answer a try and see if they work, thanks for your help.

Comment: hmm get an error running that query manually but will try the below in the rails app.

Comment: just noticed a tiny error in your query, the last part should be `ON logical_interfaces.vlan_id = pop_vlans.id` but still getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase it helps anyone, I was able to achieve this by doing:

```
@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = '" + @vlan_number.to_s + "') OR (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = 'Untagged') OR pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

if what I indicated as a remark is indeed the query you're looking for, I think you can try this

```
subQuery = Pop_vlan.all(:select=> "id,vlan_number", :joins => :logical_interfaces)

Pop_vlan.all(:select => "id,vlan_number", :conditions => ["id not in (?)", subQuery])
```

Comment: get an error `Unknown column 'pop_vlans.logical_interface_id'` which is strange, there's no `logical_interface_id` in the `pop_vlans` table, instead, it's primary key is the foreign key in `logical_interfaces`

Comment: in fact `Model.all(:joins => :table)` compiles into `SELECT * FROM "model_table" INNER JOIN "table" ON "model_table".id = "table".model_table_id`

Comment: so I should swap the the code around so that it's the opposite?